# tikz-cd: why {d} instead of {r} doesn't work?

Tags: xetex, tikz-arrows, tikz-decorations

I have tried this code:

```
\begin{tikzcd}A \arrow[tail, two heads, dashed]{r} & B\end{tikzcd}
```

I have changed {r} there to {d} and {l}
but it doesn't work, it gives an error.

What's wrong with this and how do I fix it ?

Comment: Do you understand what r l d u means here? If you use d instead of r then you're attempting to create an arrow to an entry directly below A such entry does not exist and thus error. Internally I would assume that en cells are named by coords, 1-1 for A etc. The the r l u d corresponds to a relative calculation in these coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}A \arrow[tail, two heads, dashed]{r} & B\end{tikzcd}
% 
\begin{tikzcd}A  & B \arrow[tail, two heads, dashed]{l}\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}A \arrow[tail, two heads, dashed]{d} \\ B\end{tikzcd}
% 
\begin{tikzcd}A  \\ B\arrow[tail, two heads, dashed]{u} \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

---

Diagonal arrows:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  A &                                                     \\ 
    &  \arrow[leftharpoondown, two heads, dashed]{ul} B
\end{tikzcd}
%
\begin{tikzcd}
  A \arrow[leftharpoondown, two heads, dashed]{dr} &       \\ 
                                                   & B
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}
      & A \arrow[leftharpoondown, two heads, dashed]{dl}   \\ 
  B   &
\end{tikzcd}
%
\begin{tikzcd}
                                                    & A   \\ 
  B  \arrow[leftharpoondown, two heads, dashed]{ur} &
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is good, but still is there a reason why this: `\begin{tikzcd}A \arrow[leftharpoondown, two heads, dashed]{u} \\ B\end{tikzcd}` doesn't work ?

Comment: There is nothing above of "A", to which the arrow could point, thus the error message you get.

Comment: If you want an upwards pointing arrow that connects B and A, try `\begin{tikzcd}A \\ B  \arrow[leftharpoondown, two heads, dashed]{u}\end{tikzcd}` instead.

Comment: Could you please also give an example of a **diagonal** \begin{tikzcd}A \\ B  \arrow[leftharpoondown, two heads, dashed]{u}\end{tikzcd} ? From left bottom to right top ?

Comment: @user2925716: I just updated my answer with an example on how to draw a diagonal arrow. I hpe this helps.

Comment: Is there a reason why the bottom left part is B and upper right A, and not vice versa ? with this: A \\ B ?

Comment: What does vice versa refer to? To left vs. right or to upper vs. lower?

Comment: @user2925716 the markup is the same as `array` or `align` etc in the top row you have `<nothing> & A`  and in the second row you have `B & <nothing>`  so A is top right and B is bottom left

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How do you know that you have `<nothing> & A` and not really `A & <nothing>`

Comment: @user2925716: If you take a look at the line `\begin{tikzcd}& A \\ B  \arrow[leftharpoondown, two heads, dashed]{ur} &\end{tikzcd}`  you can basically see the following pattern: `& A \\ B  &` in which `& A`is equivalent to `<nothing> & A` and `B  &` is equivalent to `B & <nothing>`. I edited the code in my answer to hopefully make the structure more obvious.

Comment: @user2925716 it is explicit in the markup: forget tikzcd  and consider `\begin{pmatrix} & A \\ B & \end{pmatrix}`  there is nothing to the left of the & on the first row and nothing to the right of the & on the second.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Right David, but you can have `\begin{pmatrix}  A & \\ &  B  \end{pmatrix}` as well ...

Comment: @user2925716: But that would result in "A" being on the top left, while "B" being on the bottomright, woulnd't it? I again updated my answer. Hopefully this time it suits your needs.

Comment: @user2925716 yes of course  you can also have  `A&B \\ C&D` and have all four cells filled, I really don't undersand your comment at all, sorry